# Условие выборки ContentResolver

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp, contentprovider

Есть ContentResolver для поиска данных  в таблице:

```
cursor = mResolver.query(getContentUri(), getListColumns(),
                    selection, null, null);
```

Хотелось бы узнать как записать в параметр selection условие выборки следующего содержания: разница между значением поля **StartDate** (тип данных `TimeStamp`) и текущей датой должна быть меньше или равна 15 минут.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

Comment: Начнем с того, что в SQLite нет типа данных `TimeStamp` - так что сначала покажите DDL скрипт создания таблицы

Comment: private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
             "create table notes (" + ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + RECIPIENT + " text not null, " + MESSAGE + " text not null, " + STIME + " text not null, "+ StartDate +" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );";